# Wrap directive with custom HTML (another directive)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Assume I have working directive called `<my-directive>`. It does some html rendering and event handling, it's thoroughly tested.

Now I'd like to wrap this directive with another wrapper directive `<wrapper>` which will render this html snippet `<div class="my-div">`, so that I could write code like this:

```
<wrapper>
   <my-directive></my-directive>
</wrapper>
```

and have:

```
<div class="my-div">
   <my-directive></my-directive>
</div>
```

How can achieve that? I've tried some approaches before, none of them seemed to be working so I'm not posting any code.

Comment: If I had a clue how to do it I would include SSCCE. If I don't know how to tackle this properly, I won't post rubbish code - sorry.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create the wrapper directive like

```
app.directive('wrapper', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div class="my-div" ng-transclude></div>'
  };
});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lAYjaP6gfwoeYPpLPPiJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 20):

It sounds like you are missing `ng-transclude` in outer template and setting `transclude` true in outer directive. The `ng-transclude` attribute tells compiler wheere to insert the inner html when `transclude` is set to `true`

```
app.directive('wrapper',function(){
 return {
   restrict:'E',
   template: '<div>Outer wrapper text<div ng-transclude></div></div>',
   transclude: true,
   replace:true
 }
});
```

DEMO http://plnkr.co/edit/sfbRyPZjqsTG6cuiaXZV?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I had to accept the other response, thought, as Arun was first. I hope you don't mind :)